# Output rule doesn't work (iptables)

Tags: iptables, firewall

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination                  
DROP       all  --  69.59.197.21         anywhere
```

I have right now this active rule. However as you can figure out, it isn't working because I'm writing this question. If I add the rule to the `INPUT chain`, it works perfectly.

Initially I thought `aaa of course, it isn't working because it's asking DNS for www.serverfault.com`, so I added the rule `iptables -A OUTPUT -s www.serverfault.com -j DROP`, but still the same.

Why is iptables allowing outgoing packets to this web?

Comment: Is it all you got in output chain? are there any other rules?

Comment: Only this one. I started today with iptables and I've been checking out how it works.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can understand you dont want to allow your server to connect to that ip so it should be dst not src.

> iptables -A OUTPUT -d 69.59.197.21  -j DROP

Comment: ok! problem of misunderstanding. I didn't notice about the -d.

Comment: No problems, glad you fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking packets with a source address of 69.59.197.21 you need to block packets with a destination address of 69.59.197.21.